# Symfony filter form for multi select dropdown values

Tags: ajax, symfony, filter, dropdown

I have a filter form which I would like to apply on a multiselect dropdown. So there's a "apply" button for the filters and when clicking it, I'd like to update the values in the dropdown according to the filter choices. (There are other fields/values on my form which should not disappear when updating the dropdown values.)

I have absolutely no clue how to achieve this. Maybe an AJAX function would lead to the solution but I don't know how such one would look like. I would be happy about any tips! :)

What I have so far:

Filter dropdowns for

- markets
- types and
- airlines

They are all multiselect dropdowns. And after selecting them I'd like to hit "apply" and then the 'documentlist'-dropdown should update so that only documents connected to the selected markets/types or airlines are shown.

P.S. What I like to implement in addition, is a search box for document names and IDs. To that I'm not even close an I don't even have the correct elements..

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
      {{ form_start(filterForm) }}
      {{ form_row(filterForm.type) }}
      {{ form_row(filterForm.markets)}}
      {{ form_row(filterForm.airlines)}}
  <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn btn-xs" value="Apply Filter" />
      {{ form_end(filterForm) }}
      <br clear="all" />
      {{ form_row(form.documentlist) }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

**update**

my form:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

      $builder
          ->setAction($options['data']['url'])
          ->setMethod('GET')
          ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
              'document_types.contract' => 1,
              'document_types.general'=>2,
              'document_types.goodwill_policy'=>3,
              'document_types.pricesheet'=>4,
              'document_types.yq_update'=>5,
              'document_types.contract_addendum'=>6),
              'choices_as_values' => true, 'label' => 'label.types',
              'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
              'label' => 'label.type',
              'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))

      ;

      $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

      $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($user){
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // only show specific filters based on user's context

        $form->add('airlines', 'entity', array(
          'class' => 'AppBundle:Airline', 'property' => 'id',
          'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
            $airlines = $user->getAirlines();
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
              ->addOrderBy('a.id', 'ASC')
              ->andWhere('a.id IN (?1)')
              ->setParameter(1,$airlines);
            },
          'choice_value' => 'id',
          'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.airlines',
          'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
          'translation_domain' => 'Documents'));

        $form->add('markets', 'entity', array(
          'class' => 'AppBundle:Market', 'property' => 'id',
          'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
            $markets = $user->getMarkets();
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
              ->addOrderBy('m.id', 'ASC');
              ->andWhere('m.id IN (?1)')
              ->setParameter(1,$markets);
            },
          'choice_value' => 'id',
          'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.markets',
          'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
          'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))
```

and that's the dropdown, that's supposed to update its content after the previous dropdowns are selected.

```
    ->add('documentlist', EntityType::class, array(
           'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Document',
              'property' => 'name',
              'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
              'label' => 'label.document_list',
              'empty_value' => "Select document",
              'required' => false,
              'mapped' => false,
              'translation_domain' => 'Documents'} )); 
}
```

Comment: You must have some more code than this Sonja. Are your filters checkboxes? If so, use jQuery or plain old Javascript to detect onChange for the filter checkboxes, then update the dropdown lists. Without showing more of your form code, it's very hard to give any more advice.

Comment: Sure there is more code! But I don't know what parts would help you? I said "they are all multiselect dropdowns" :) So I could use jQuery, I guess but I wouldn't know how the function onChange would look like!

Comment: it would be good if you reviewed some of your previous questions and selected a checkmark by the correct answers. I see you've only checked one question.

Comment: To be honest, none of the answers helped me, that's why I didn't check them. I will check your answer for improving my last code

Comment: None of the answers have helped you because you are not familiar with Symfony. It takes a long time to learn Symfony. You can look at [my Symfony articles](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/tag/symfony/) for reference. I have a number of useful articles that might help you. You also need to do a lot of work to fully get familiar with Symfony. I can tell by the way people ask the questions whether they are familiar with Symfony or not.

Comment: i never said that I'm familiar with symfony. Is it a crime? :D I still have to work with it, can't help that I have questions!

Comment: I'm somewhat sympathetic to Alvin's comment, Sonja. On Stack Overflow we used to have a measure of "acceptance rate" on people's profile cards, to indicate how much they accepted answers. They were removed, but I thought they were rather useful: they indicated that both questioners and askers have a shared goal to improving acceptance rates. If you solved things yourself in each particular case, do please add an answer of your own, and accept it, if you prefer it to another answer - that is very welcome here.

Comment: (Personally, if someone got me a 90% solution, I give them the tick, and then add my own answer to build on it, but that's just me).

Comment: ok sorry. I'm super new here, so I wasn't aware of that, but now I know :)

Comment: No worries, it's all good. You're doing fine - just remember to don your Kevlar jacket and you'll be OK `:=)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm guessing you're doing an application for Airlines based on your previous posts. Below is some examples that should help you:

```
// Your PHP Form file
...
->add('local_markets_bool', CheckboxType::class, array( // Show Local Markets?
        'label' => 'Local markets:',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array(
                'onchange' => "filter('local_markets')"
        ),
))
...
```

---

```
{# Your Twig file #}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('script/filters.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
// Your Javascript file. Example web/script/filters.js
function filter(type){
    var markList = document.getElementById("form_market_list");
    var optSub = "<option value='' selected='selected'>Choose an option</option>";

    if (type == 'local_markets'){   // Local.
        optSub += "<option value='us'>USA</option>";
        optSub += "<option value='ca'>Canada</option>";
    }
    else if (degType == 'americas'){    // TC Degree.
        optSub += "<option value='us'>USA</option>";
        optSub += "<option value='ca'>Canada</option>";
        optSub += "<option value='pa'>Panama</option>";
        optSub += "<option value='br'>Brazil</option>";
        optSub += "<option value='pe'>Peru</option>";
    }
    ...
    markList.innerHTML = optSub;
}
```

Then when you click the `local_markets_bool` checkbox, that triggers and onchange() event, and passes in the parameter `local_markets` and then the code adds the Countries USA and Canada to the list.

You might not want to do it that way, but it gives you and idea. Using jQuery is easier, but the example is just plain Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! My problem is that, I'm referring to doctrine entries and not hardcoded dropdown entries, so I can't really pick up on your code..

Comment: Sure you can. Are you saying your form is using [ChoiceType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) and you are using a callable in the choice_value to populate the drop-down list? If so, the list is just populated. You can still modify it. You really haven't told us what you are doing in your Form Class?

Comment: I'm using an EntityType since they are 'multiselect dropdowns'. I updated the post with code from my form type